# How to configure Minio sourced from a subfolder in a single bucket in Docker?

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, docker-swarm, minio

I am trying to find a way to configure MinIO using Docker to back-end into a single S3 bucket, enabling my client to expose S3 capabilities to their internal customers.

To meet some very specialized compliance rules in an air-gapped environment, my client was provisioned a single bucket in an on-premise S3-compatible solution. They cannot get additional buckets but need to provide their internal organizational customers access to S3 capabilities, including the ability to leverage buckets, ACLs, etc. The requirement is to use their existing S3 storage bucket and not other on-premise storage.

I tried Minio gateway but it tries to create and manage new buckets on the underlying S3 provider. I couldn't find anything like a "prefix" capability I could supply to force it to only work inside {host}/{bucketName} instead of the root endpoint for their keys.

Minio server might work but we'd need to mount a docker volume to their underlying bucket and I'm concerned about the solution becoming brittle. Also, I can't seem to find any well-regarded, production-ready, vendor-supported S3 volume drivers. Since I don't have a volume plugin, I haven't validated performance yet, though I'm concerned it will be sub-par as well.

How can I, in a docker environment, make gateway work to provide bucket/user/management capabilities all rooted in a single underlying bucket/folder? I'm open to alternative designs provided I can meet the customer's requirements (run via docker, store in their underlying S3 storage, provide ability to provision and secure new buckets).

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Negative. We ended up moving to a different storage solution altogether.